# Load a partial view with parameters

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I have a big main Bean `DetalleSolicitudTneBean.java` which contains a lot of information. I'm distributing the information in many partial views because each partial view depends on the data obtained from the main view.

```
@RequestScoped
@Named("detalleSolicitudTneBean")
@URLJoins(joins = { @URLJoin(path = "/web/detalle_solicitud_tne/{refExp}", to = "/pages/web/detalle_solicitud_tne.jsf") })
public class DetalleSolicitudTneBean extends BaseBeanImpl implements Serializable
{
    @URLParameter
    private String refExp;

    @Inject
    private TrAPIUI apiUI;

    private TrExpediente trExpediente;

    @URLAction(ingorePostback = true, views = { "/pages/web/detalle_solicitud_tne.jsf" })
    public void cargarDatosSolicitud()
    {
        //a lot of code
        trExpediente = apiUI.obtenerExpedientes(refExp);//returns one trExpediente object
        //more code
    }

    public TrExpediente getTrExpediente()
    {       return trExpediente;    }
    public void setTrExpediente(TrExpediente trExpediente)
    {       this.trExpediente = trExpediente;   }
}
```

Then I have the `detalle_solicitud_tne.xhtml` of this main Bean which calls `detalle_solicitud_persona`

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:g="http://www.guadaltel.es/jsf2"
template="/layout/#{layout.template}/office_level.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="body">
        <legend>Detalles de la solicitud</legend>
        <!-- I want to call my page detalle_solicitud_persona here passing the parameter trExpediente-->
        <loadMyPartialView src="detalle_solicitud_persona(#{detalleSolicitudTneBean.trExpediente})"/>
        <!-- many other partial view calls -->
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Finally I have my second Bean and its partial view which is called from `detalle_solicitud_tne.xhtml`

```
@RequestScoped //is this scope ok?
@Named("detalleSolicitudPersona")
@URLJoins(joins = { @URLJoin(path = "/web/detalle_solicitud_persona", to = "/pages/web/detalle_solicitud_persona.jsf") })
public class DetalleSolicitudPersona extends BaseBeanImpl implements Serializable
{
    @Inject
    private IPersonasDao personasDao;

    private Personas personas;

    //I need this method to be called to fill the class atributes before get any atribute from the class
    public void cargarDatosSolicitud()
    {
        personas = personasDao.getPersonasByexp(trExpediente);
        //fill and set many other info
    }

    //getters y setters
    public Personas getPersonas()
    {       return personas;    }

    public void setPersonas(Personas personas)
    {       this.personas = personas;   }
}
```

And its view `detalle_solicitud_persona.xhtml`

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:g="http://www.guadaltel.es/jsf2">

    <p:outputPanel>
        <p:fieldset>
            <legend>Información personal</legend>
            <div class="form-group">
                <g:label value="Nombre" id="nombre">
                    <h:outputText value="Nombre" />
                </g:label>
                <div>
                    <h:outputText id="runFilter" value="#{detalleSolicitudPersona.personas.persPrimerNombre}" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- many other class atributes -->
        </p:fieldset>
    </p:outputPanel>
</ui:composition>
```

So, to resume, I need to load my personas data in my second Bean depending on the parameter `trExpediente` received from my main view to display the data from `personas` in my second partial view.

Comment: loading partial views is done via an `ui:include` which you can pass parameters to. Tried that?

Comment: I have tried something like this `<ui:include src="detalle_solicitud_persona.xhtml"><ui:param name="trExpediente" value="#{detalleSolicitudTneBean.trExpediente}"/></ui:include>` but I can't make it work on the bean. I mean, I don't know how to rescue the `trExpediente` value